# I could not query with different condition in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Operator Models:

```
const operatorSchema = new Schema({
    operatorName: {
        type: String
    },

    users:[{
        email:String,
        payment:Number,
        paymentsData: Date,
        product: String,

      }],


});
```

I need to filter by operatorName and email in users block. But when I try with this I get all users in related OperatorName how can I query correctly ?

```
 Operators.find( { $and: [{operatorName: operatorName},  {'users.email': 'super@m.com'}]}, function (err, docs) {
      ) {

    if (err) console.log(err)
    else {
        docs.forEach(function(data){ 
        console.log(data)
         })
        // res.render('total_earns_operator_tables', { operators: docs });
    } 
  });
```

**EDIT**

I also try with aggregate method like this but again, I get same result and I gel all bunch of user data, but I want only demouser@mail.com

```
  Operators.aggregate([
        { $match: {$and: [{ operatorName: operatorName},{'users.email': 
         'demouser@mail.com' }]}},
        ]
    ,function (err, docs) {   
        // console.log(Operators)
        //  Operators.find( { $and: [{operatorName: operatorName},  {users: {$elemMatch: {email:['super@m.com']}}}]}, function (err, docs) {
            // Operators.find( {operatorName: operatorName,  "users.email": "demouser@mail.com"}, function (err, docs) {

        if (err) console.log(err)
        else {
            docs.forEach(function(data){ 
            console.log(data)
             })
            // res.render('total_earns_operator_tables', { operators: docs });
        } 
      });
```

It is very basic but I couldnt find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. It is returning all documents that satisfy you two criteria: 1. having a specified `operatorName` and 2. users array having at least one user matching the specified email.

If you want to **reashape** your documents by filtering the user array to only include the user matching your condition, you'll have to use an aggregation.

**EDIT**

As per your edit: Your aggregation only have a `$match` stage, which is identical to your query above. To change the shape of a document, the aggregation framework provides you with the `$project` stage, see the example below:

```
Operators.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      operatorName: operatorName,
      "users.email": "demouser@mail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      operatorName: '$operatorName',
      users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$users",
          as: "user",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$user.email",
              "demouser@mail.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here, we first filter the collection to get only the documents you want, using the `$match` stage, then we use the [`$filter`](https://mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)operator in `$project` stage, to return only the matching users within the array.

See the [working playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VDxOo_pYsrs)

Comment: Please check my question again, I added aggreagation method but when I use that, I also get all users data where is my fault ?

Comment: I added below the EDIT part, please check ? @ISAE